# How to set QML MapPolyline Path Property

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have a `MapPolyline` object in my QtQuick Project. I need to change the path property from the C++ file, but I have no idea how to do that.

**My qml - File:**

```
MapPolyline {
    id: mapline
    objectName: "MapLine"
    line.width: 5
    line.color: "green"
    path:
    {[
        { latitude: 47.219791, longitude: 9.546032 },
        { latitude: 47.219657, longitude: 9.542508 },
        { latitude: 47.2194446, longitude: 9.5437876 }
    ]}
}
```

And now I want to change the content of the path property from the C++ file.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: See this answer it explains how to have draw the path on map [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48071952/qml-how-to-change-mappolyline-path-from-c/48073062#48073062)

Answer (score 3):

Qt Location works okay from c++. You don't need to mess with any QJSValue stuff. Create a property in your QObject and return a QVariantList. Fill the QVariantList with QGeoCoordinate (the points in your line). In QML set the MapPolyline's path to the QObject QVariantList property. QML will automatically convert the QVariantList into a Javascript Array. QGeoCoordinates are qml coordinate type so the conversion is transparent. Any time you see a "list" type in qml, you can always return QVariantList from c++ or QVariantMap if you want to populate a Javascript Object (or create a Q_GADGET).

One thing that got me was that my QGeoCoordinates returned from c++ wasn't valid. If the QGeoCoordinates are invalid, the MapPolyLine fail to populate and will create a message: "Unsupported path type". Make sure QGeoCoordinate isValid() before adding it to the QVariantList.

Comment: Using a conversion to `QVariantList` is a very good hint, which worked for me: `path->property("path").value<QVariantList>();`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Qt Location, but in general I think it's better to assume that if C++ access to a particular (QML) API was intended, there'd be a C++ API for it. I remember that [this mailing list thread](http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/interest/2015-July/018172.html) mentioned that there was a [work-in-progress change](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/115647/) that adds a C++ API.

That being said, if you're curious and think it'd be fun to try anyway, you should take a look at the [`QDeclarativePolylineMapItem::setPath()`](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtlocation.git/tree/src/imports/location/qdeclarativepolylinemapitem.cpp#n515) function, which calls [`parseCoordinate()`](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtlocation.git/tree/src/imports/location/locationvaluetypehelper.cpp#n40) to do the actual parsing of the path. It would probably involve using `QObject::findObject()` (or the property system) to obtain the `MapPolyline` object in C++, and then constructing a `QJSValue` (using the functions available in `QJSEngine`) that matches the expected format of `setPath()`.