# QML. How to change MapPolyline path from C++?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

Here is a QML map:

```
Map {
        anchors.fill: parent
        plugin: osmMapPlugin
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(56.006355, 92.860984)
        zoomLevel: 14

        MapPolyline {
            line.width: 3
            line.color: 'red'
            path: [
                { latitude: -27, longitude: 153.0 },
                { latitude: -27, longitude: 154.1 },
                { latitude: -28, longitude: 153.5 },
                { latitude: -29, longitude: 153.5 }
            ]
        }
    }
```

How to change `path` from `C++/qt`? I tried this:

QML:

```
Map {
        anchors.fill: parent
        plugin: osmMapPlugin
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(56.006355, 92.860984)
        zoomLevel: 14

        MapPolyline {
            line.width: 3
            line.color: 'red'

            path: map_path
        }
    }
```

C++:

```
map = new QQuickWidget();
map->setSource(QUrl("qrc:map.qml"));

QQmlContext *qml_map = map->rootContext();
QGeoPath *path = new QGeoPath();
path->addCoordinate(*(new QGeoCoordinate(56.0831528053, 92.8405031454)));
path->addCoordinate(*(new QGeoCoordinate(56.1, 93)));
qml_map->setContextProperty("map_path", path);
```

But I got a exception:

```
calling a private constructor of class 'QVariant':
    qml_map->setContextProperty("map_path", path);
```

and

```
attempted to use of deleted function:
    qml_map->setContextProperty("map_path", path);
```

**UPD:**
@hi-im-frogatto suggested that it was necessary to do so:

```
qml_map->setContextProperty("map_path", QVariant::fromValue(path));
```

It helped, the error no longer occurs. But the line is not drawn. Got error:

```
qrc:map.qml:30: ReferenceError: map_path is not defined
qrc:map.qml:21:5: QML Map: Plugin is a write-once property, and cannot be set again.
```

Comment: Do you want to change the values of Path, or set it from C ++?

Comment: @eyllanesc set from C++

Comment: @eyllanesc I added to the question

Comment: @eyllanesc I added to the question again....

Comment: Just as a side note, `path->addCoordinate(*(new QGeoCoordinate(56.0831528053, 92.8405031454)));` leaks memory. Remove the `*(new` altogether, and the matching `)`

Comment: @VincentFourmond Oh my God, I looked at my code after two years of studying C++ and was horrified 0_0
Incredible stupidity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it says [@HiI'mFrogatto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1841194/hi-im-frogatto) you should use `QVariant::fromValue()`, but it can not be used directly on the .qml side:

```
QGeoPath geopath;
geopath.addCoordinate(QGeoCoordinate(56.006355, 92.860984));
geopath.addCoordinate(QGeoCoordinate(56.1, 93));
geopath.addCoordinate(QGeoCoordinate(56.1, 92.777));


QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("geopath", QVariant::fromValue(geopath));
```

what you have to do is access each element through a loop:

```
Map {
    anchors.fill: parent
    plugin: osmMapPlugin
    center: QtPositioning.coordinate(56.006355, 92.860984)
    zoomLevel: 10

    MapPolyline {
        id: pl
        line.width: 3
        line.color: 'red'
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        var lines = []
        for(var i=0; i < geopath.size(); i++){
            lines[i] = geopath.coordinateAt(i)
        }
        pl.path = lines
    }
}
```

---

But with this case we can not update the values of the QGeoPath, it is appropriate to implement a class that inherits from QObject and has as property to QGeoPath, since you can manipulate it from C++ or from QML.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGeoPath>
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QTimer>

class PathController: public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QGeoPath geopath READ geoPath WRITE setGeoPath NOTIFY geopathChanged)
public:
    PathController(QObject *parent=0):QObject(parent){}
    void test(){
        mGeoPath.addCoordinate(QGeoCoordinate(56.006355, 92.860984));
        mGeoPath.addCoordinate(QGeoCoordinate(56.1, 93));
        mGeoPath.addCoordinate(QGeoCoordinate(56.1, 92.777));
        QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);

        QObject::connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, [this](){
            mGeoPath.translate(0.001, -0.01);
            emit geopathChanged();
        });
        timer->start(1000);

    }
    QGeoPath geoPath() const{return mGeoPath;}
    void setGeoPath(const QGeoPath &geoPath){
        if(geoPath == mGeoPath)
            return;
        mGeoPath = geoPath;
        emit geopathChanged();
    }

signals:
    void geopathChanged();
private:
    QGeoPath mGeoPath;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if defined(Q_OS_WIN)
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    PathController controller;
    controller.test();

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("pathController", &controller);

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;
    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

import QtLocation 5.6
import QtPositioning 5.6

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Plugin {
        id: osmMapPlugin
        name: "osm"
    }

    Map {
        anchors.fill: parent
        plugin: osmMapPlugin
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(56.006355, 92.860984)
        zoomLevel: 10

        MapPolyline {
            id: pl
            line.width: 10
            line.color: 'red'
        }
    }

    function loadPath(){
        var lines = []
        for(var i=0; i < pathController.geopath.size(); i++){
            lines[i] = pathController.geopath.coordinateAt(i)
        }
        return lines;
    }
    Connections{
        target: pathController
        onGeopathChanged: pl.path = loadPath()
    }

    Component.onCompleted: pl.path = loadPath()
}
```

In this [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/48071952) you will find the complete example.

Answer (score 3):

[`QQmlContext::setContextProperty`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlcontext.html#setContextProperty-1) accepts a [`QVariant`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/qvariant.html) and there's no any implicit conversion from [`QGeoPath`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgeopath.html) to [`QVariant`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/qvariant.html). However using the following method you can do this:

```
qml_map->setContextProperty("map_path", QVariant::fromValue(path));
```

More info: http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/positioning-cpp-qml.html

Comment: Errors does not produce, but line, unfortunately, never showed up. Get an error. Updated the question.

Comment: @dtcobra `setContextProperty` should be called before `setSource`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer I found here - [How to set QML MapPolyline Path Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32585037/how-to-set-qml-mappolyline-path-property) - I wrote a simple test-case which is correct, works and, most importantly, is simpler than the accepted answer on this question.

The principle is simple - we can wrap our `QGeoCoordinate`s in `QVariant`s. We can add the `QVariant`s to a `QVariantList`, and pass that directly to the QML `MapPolyline.path` property.

Even better, if we do this with a C++ class' `Q_PROPERTY` value, we don't even have to have QML logic to read or re-read the property when it changes.

Finally, with this method you can call `setContextProperty` after the `QQmlWidget` has loaded its source and begun displaying, which is useful if, for example, your `QQmlWidget` is part of a Qt Designer form file instead of added explicitly in C++.

Lets take a look at how this looks in practice - I'm going to create a class called `RouteProvider` which provides the path:

```cpp
#ifndef ROUTEPROVIDER_H
#define ROUTEPROVIDER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <qqml.h>
#include <QMetaClassInfo>
#include <QGeoPath>

class RouteProvider : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QVariantList path READ path NOTIFY pathUpdated)
    QML_ELEMENT

public:
    explicit RouteProvider(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    QVariantList path();

signals:
    void pathUpdated();

private:
    QVariantList m_path;
};

#endif // ROUTEPROVIDER_H
```

To pass this class as a context property, the following needs to be true:

- The class must be a subclass of `QObject`

  - This might actually be something you can skip using `Q_GADGET` and `Q_REGISTER_METATYPE` but that way lies madness
- the class must use the `QML_ELEMENT` macro in the private part of its declaration

Note that your `m_path` and class functions can, in theory, be anything and do anything. The important aspects are:

- The `path` function should return the `QVariantList` of `QVariant::fromValue(QGeoCoordinate)` values
- Functions that change the path should emit the `pathUpdated` signal.

Looking at the `.cpp` file for this example is very simple:

```cpp
#include "routeprovider.h"

RouteProvider::RouteProvider(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    m_path.append(QVariant::fromValue(QGeoCoordinate(51.50648, -0.12927)));
    m_path.append(QVariant::fromValue(QGeoCoordinate(51.50826, -0.12599)));
}

QVariantList RouteProvider::path()
{
    return m_path;
}
```

For the sake of this demonstration, I'm just creating a line between two coordinates and returning the path.

I'm going to create a `QMainWindow` with a `QQmlWidget` as its central widget, then set an instance of this class as a context property.

```cpp
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "routeprovider.h"

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    RouteProvider m_provider;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

To demonstrate this method still works even after the QML file has been loaded, I'm loading the QML file first, then setting the context property:

```cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QQuickWidget>
#include <QQmlContext>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    auto centralWidget = new QQuickWidget(this);
    centralWidget->setSource(QUrl{"qrc:/CentralMap.qml"});
    centralWidget->rootContext()->setContextProperty("routeProvider", &m_provider);
    centralWidget->setResizeMode(QQuickWidget::SizeRootObjectToView);

    this->setCentralWidget(centralWidget);
    this->resize(400, 400);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
}
```

And here's the simplest kind of QML file which still demonstrates this in action:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtPositioning 5.12
import QtLocation 5.15

Item {
    Plugin {
        id: mapPlugin
        name: "osm"
    }

    Map {
        anchors.fill: parent
        zoomLevel: 14
        plugin: mapPlugin

        MapPolyline {
            id: line
            path: routeProvider.path
            line.width: 15
            line.color: 'red'
        }
    }
}
```

Place it in a `.qrc` file to make it available to the program at run-time.

Finally, a default-generated main function starts our application:

```cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Result:

[image: Resulting application window showing map of London with red line]